# Jenkins pipline pruned branches are not deleted from disk

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins will create a new build job within the pipline when a new branch is created. When that branch is merged and pruned jenkins will remove it from the UI, as the scan picks it up. But the job folder for that old branch remains on the disk. Some of my repos are 2g+ by the time we clone, pull in dependencies and build. The pipelines are quickly using all the disk space.

How can I force jenkins to delete the folders belonging to pruned branches?

### Update

It looks like the intended behaviour of Jenkins is to delete the job, but not the workspace files for piplines, you must delete those yourself. The finally block of my pipeline now has the following:

```
cleanWs()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an option for you, Simply delete the workspace as last step of your build with [cleanWs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ws-cleanup/#cleanws-delete-workspace-when-build-is-done). Of course you'll need to install the plugin.

You could also delete the a specific directory  using [deleteDir](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-deletedir-code-recursively-delete-the-current-directory-from-the-workspace). This could be the directory  in which the nuget packages are stored. Also run `nuger restore` **without** `nocache` parameter

One more option is to simply run `git clean -xfd` as a bat step at  the end, this is deleting
all thr folders and files not under source  control. Of course this implies that workspace Root is the got repo Rroot. be careful if you are  saving some build logs or something that you need but it's not under git

Comment: Thats not ideal. Should jenkins not be deleting the folder when a branch is pruned? Deleting everything at the end of a build would make the build, clone everything again and download all the dependencies again.

Comment: You didn't say what kind of dependency manager you are using nor for what, but if it doesn't cache stuff that downloads once in a global cache, it's not good. You didn't also say if you are using Multibranch build? I imagine yes, if not then I don't understand how would deleting the workspace at the end make the build.

Comment: These are mostly .net build, that bring in a lot of nuget packages to the local folder. I'll try to delete at the end of every build, and see how that works

Comment: Ok, but it's Multibranch build then?

Comment: Yes - sorry multi- branch. I had though jenkins was deleting the folders when branches were pruned